# Testing subdomains in Azure staging

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, subdomain, azure-web-roles

I just added a new area to my MVC application hosted in an Azure Web Role that uses [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/#subdomains) to hit subdomain controllers for routes with subdomain prefixes. On the azure emulator this works great and I can hit the correct controllers using my development url (for which I have a record in the host file)

host file record:              `127.0.0.1      domain.com     portal.domain.com`

working subdomain route:     `http://portal.domain.com:81/SubController/SubAction`

How can I continue to test this in a staging environment? At the moment I'm using the 3-month free trial and I understand I can't add a CNAME or A record until I start paying but I still have 2 months in the trial and simply want the application to WORK.  It doesn't have to look pretty I don't care if the subdomain url looks like this:

```
  http://portal.8c72d21eg2c14636s0542f181024e72a.cloudapp.net/
```

This currently throws:

```
 [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "portal.8c72d21eg2c14636s0542f181024e72a.cloudapp.net" failed. No such host is known
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Are you sure a CName wouldn't work? You couldn't simply make `portal.mydomain.com` and `somethingelse.mydomain.com` point to `8c72d21eg2c14636s0542f181024e72a.cloudapp.net` to get this working?

Comment: Actually, you sir are correct. I was mixing up the instructions for azure website (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) which states reserved/shared mode is requires vs azure service (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) which states no such thing. You may post as answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you already noted, there is no limitation for CNAME against `Cloud Services`.

Secondly, I will strongly suggest using `production` environment even for testing/staging purposes, especially when developing / testing. The only difference between a Cloud Service `staging` and `production` environments is that you get a `fixed/stable` domain name for your production environment (i.e. `mygreatapp.cloudapp.net`), while you always get a different GUID-like domain for staging with every deployment (i.e. `8c72d21eg2c14636s0542f181024e72a.cloudapp.net`). Other than that, everything is the same - billing, networking, resources, everything.

Given the specifics, you understand that you have to create a new CNAME every time you deploy a new version (if you deleted old staging) to staging, because you will be given a new GUID-like domain.

So, create your cloud service, CNAME your domain to its domain, deploy to `production` slot and live happily ever after ;)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but actually my staging GUID stays the same every time I publish the solution so this is not a problem for me. I think the GUID will probably change if I delete the entire deployment but not when I "update" it via publish

Comment: true. if you delete (staging) deployment, next time you deploy it will be a new GUID. If you just update/upgrade it will be the same and won't change.